# PHP default hash function safety

Tags: php, hash, password-protection, password-hash

As we know, `md5` is totally unsafe these days and i wonder if the default `password_hash()` has already been cracked?
Could you tell me what hashing algorithm does it use in the default?
And what are the best hashing algorithms to this day (for password storing).
Thanks.

Comment: Use salt, private one, thats give you more secure, no matter what is the hashing type, salt make it more secure and powerfull.

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi No

Comment: If you look at the PHP manual, you will see that `password_hash()` is still the recomended method. It has also been written in a way that they can change the default hash algoritm IF it should ever prove less than perfect with a simple update of PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly why?

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) specifically the bit in Pink

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi Mainly because people dont create very good salts if left to their own devises. They tend to use the same salt for all there hashings `password_hash()` creates a new GOOD salt for each hash

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah i read it, and i'm doing as you said, every user has his own salt. complex salt with alphabets, numbers and codes. i hope i'm not wrong by doing this.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the password_hash() algorithm. It uses the Blowfish password algorithm by default (but you can change it). The salt option of this of the method is now deprecated in php 7.0.0 and uses the salt that is automatically generated.

for more information, go have a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php